# Save and read arrays Image into UserDefaults swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I want to save images in an array using UserDefaults in Swift 3

```
   var arrayImage = [UIImage]()
   arrayImage.append(UIImage(data: dataImage as! Data)!) //add image to array
    globalD.set(arrayImage, forKey: "FavoritesContactStandardImage")
```

I'm doing it that way, but it does not save, how can I save it and then read it?

Comment: It is a really, really bad idea to save one image to UserDefaults. Trying to save an array of images is even worse. Write each image to a file.

Comment: Save the images in a temporary directory and only save the path for that images in de user defaults, as rmaddy says, it is a really bad bad idea to save images in the defaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try these. You just use saveImages & loadImages functions.
But you need to implement delete function by yourself.

```
let key = "FavoritesContactStandardImage"

func getImageKey(_ index:Int) -> String {
    return "\(key)\(index)"
}

func saveImages(_ images:[UIImage]) {
    var list = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: key) as? [String] ?? [String]()
    var index = list.count

    for image in images {
        let imgKey = getImageKey(index)
        saveImage(imgKey, image)
        list.append(imgKey)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(list, forKey: key)
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        index += 1
    }
}

func saveImage(_ imageName:String, _ image:UIImage) {
    let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
    let imgPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: path.appendingPathComponent(imageName))

    do {
        try UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)?.write(to: imgPath, options: .atomic)
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

func loadImages() -> [UIImage] {
    let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
    let list = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: key) as? [String] ?? [String]()
    var imageList = [UIImage]()
    for (index, _) in list.enumerated() {
        let imageName = getImageKey(index)
        let imgPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: path.appendingPathComponent(imageName))
        if let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imgPath.path) {
            imageList.append(image)
        }
    }
    return imageList
}
```

Hope that's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

That's a really bad idea to save image data on **UserDefault** , maybe better if you save the image name (if you put your image on assets catalog) / image path (if your put your image on custom directory on your project ). And if you want to save the downloaded image from services maybe you can save your downloaded image to a directory before you get the paath and save to UserDefault